# SQL connection string for local db

Tags: sql-server, connection, connection-string, localdb

I want to connect to database with this connection string

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\4L46D\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\create table\create table\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True");
```

but I get the following error:
get red line on address of database file:

> AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\4L46D\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\create table\create table\Database1.mdf

[image]

Could you please help to how write the connection string?

**solution** :
use @ before first double quotation(") and delete " from database path .
use like this :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\4L46D\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\create table\create table\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

Comment: i just copy connection string and paste to sqlconnection().i have upload the picture.

Comment: Please add your error as text not image.

Comment: red line on address of database file (syntax error)AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\4L46D\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\create table\create table\Database1.mdf

Comment: [Edit] directly into your question.

Comment: How can i define the address of database file in connection string?

Answer (score 1):

To use inverted commas with in string. you need to escape character with backslash i.e (\)

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\4L46D\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\create table\\create table\\Database1.mdf\";Integrated Security=True");
```

Comment: Do you found this answer useful ?

Comment: No .not work for me .thnx anyway .the solution added the post